# Get dollar total of all elements with class using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, math

I have the following html:

```
<div class="balance">
    <div class="heading">
        <p class="total"><span>00</span></p>
    </div>
    <div class="instance withdrawal">
        <h3>Random</h3>
        <p>desc</p>
        <p class="amount">$350.<span>00</span></p>
    </div>
    <div class="instance deposit">
        <h3>Added in</h3>
        <p>desc</p>
        <p class="amount">$1,250.<span>00</span></p>
    </div>
    <div class="instance withdrawal">
        <h3>Bill</h3>
        <p>desc</p>
        <p class="amount">$50.<span>00</span></p>
    </div>
</div>
<!--end wallet-container left-->
```

How can i use jQuery to add take total deposits, subtract the withdrawals and append it to the p.total?

Comment: Are you assured that this is what your markup is going to look like? If so, it's a bit wonky, but shouldn't be too difficult to accomplish

Comment: Yep. Why is the markup wonky?  The span elements are used to style the cent amount

Comment: I wouldn't have thought to separate the cents from the main amount, nor style them any differently, though it should be valid

Comment: kindly include the JS as well not only the html..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adjusting `html` slightly by placing `$` character before first `span` element containing whole number including second sibling `span` element containing decimal number as descendants of `.deposit` , `.withdrawal` elements; utilizing `data-*` attribute to reference object containing `withdrawal` , `deposit`, `total` properties;  `Array.prototype.reduce()` ;  `Number()` ; `String.prototype.replace()` for comma `,` character ; `.each()`

```js
var res = {
  deposit: 0,
  withdrawal: 0,
  total: 0
};

function calculate(el) {
  return el.get().reduce(function(a, b) {
    return Number(a.textContent.replace(/,/g, "")) + Number(b.textContent)
  })
}

$(".deposit, .withdrawal").each(function(i, el) {
  res[$(el).data().type] += calculate($("span", el))
})

res.total = res.deposit - res.withdrawal;

$(".total span").html(res.total);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div class="balance">
  <div class="heading">
    <p class="total" data-type="total"><span>00</span>
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="instance withdrawal" data-type="withdrawal">
    <h3>Random</h3>
    <p>desc</p>
    <p class="amount">$<span>350</span><span>.00</span>
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="instance deposit" data-type="deposit">
    <h3>Added in</h3>
    <p>desc</p>
    <p class="amount">$<span>1,250</span><span>.00</span>
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="instance withdrawal" data-type="withdrawal">
    <h3>Bill</h3>
    <p>desc</p>
    <p class="amount">$<span>50</span><span>.00</span>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
<!--end wallet-container left-->
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kiirosora/L7yaxhoc/).

Edited to take floating points into account.

**JS**

```
$(function() {
  var total = 0;

  // Check each instance
  $('.instance').each(function() {
    var
      $this = $(this),
      clone = $this.find('.amount').clone(),
      amount = 0,
      floating = 0;

    // Get floating point
    floating = parseFloat('0.' + clone.find('span').text());
    clone.find('span').remove();

    // Get integer amount
    amount = parseInt(clone.text().replace(/\D+/gim, ''), 10);

    if (!isNaN(amount) && amount > 0) {
      if ($this.is('.deposit')) total += (amount + floating); // Deposit
      else if ($this.is('.withdrawal')) total -= (amount + floating); // Withdrawal
    }
  });

  // Format total with commas
  var formatted = ('' + parseInt(total, 10)).split('').reverse().join('');
  formatted = formatted.replace(/(\d{3})/gim, '$1,');
  formatted = formatted.split('').reverse();
  if (formatted[0] == ',') formatted.shift();
  formatted = formatted.join('');

  $('.total').text('$' + parseInt(formatted, 10) + '.');

  var decimal = (total - parseInt(total, 10)) * 100;
  $('.total').append('<span>' + decimal + '</span>')
});
```

Comment: It works for the author's example, but you should parseFloat in case of decimals in the deposits/withdrawals, so you shouldn't remove the "useless" `<span>`. Moreover, try to not use `parseInt` without the second argument, it's misleading.

Comment: @Tomisol thanks for pointing that out, I edited the code. I was not aware of the second parameter for parseInt(), thanks for mentioning.